# Проверка на заполненность поля. PHP

Tags: php, битрикс

Вопрос такой как при условии заполнено ли поле, выводить html c полями PHP.
Пробую так:

```html
<td width="50%" style="padding-left: 20px" valign="top">
                        <p style="font-size: 12pt;"><strong>
                                <?if (is_null($arItemClients['UF_GENDIR'])):?>
                                    Директору<br>
                                    <?=$arItemClient['UF_SHORTNAME']?><br>
                                    <?=$arItemClient['UF_DIRECTOR']?> <br>
                                    <?=$arItemClient['UF_JUR_ADRESS']?> <br>
                                    <?=$arItemClient['UF_POST_ADRESS']?> <br>
                                    Тел: <?=$arItemClient['UF_DIRECTOR_MOB']?><br>
                                <?else:?>
                                    Генеральному директору<br>
                                    <?=$arItemClient['UF_SHORTNAME']?><br>
                                    <?=$arItemClient['UF_GENDIR']?><br>
                                    <?=$arItemClient['UF_JUR_ADRESS']?> <br>
                                    <?=$arItemClient['UF_POST_ADRESS']?> <br>                                                 Тел: <?=$arItemClient['UF_GENDIR_MOB']?><br>
                                <?endif;?>
                                e-mail: <a href="mailto:<?=$arItemClient['EMAIL']?>"><?=$arItemClient['EMAIL']?></a>
                            </strong></p>
                    </td>
```

При условии, что не заполнено поле "Генеральный директор" выводить текст Директору и поля которые к нему относятся, а если заполнено то выводить все по Генеральному директору.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать вместо `is_null()` `empty()` http://php.net/empty

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов пробывал `empty()` та же петрушка

Comment: Что покажет `var_dump()` массива `$arItemClients`?

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов покажет много чего, массив не пустой, все поля по которым идет проверка есть и они заполнены

Comment: Что содержится в поле `UF_GENDIR`?

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов [UF_GENDIR] =>Иванов Иван Иванович

Comment: Хм в этом случаи `empty()` должен вернуть `false` и вывести секцию `Генеральному директору`. Я правильно понимаю, что выводится список всех директоров в цикле?